# How to exclude a single field from json serialization with json_serializable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable to generate Json serialization for my classes. This works fine. Now I would like to ignore a single field only for the json generation but not when reading a json e.g. the dateOfBirth in following example:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Person {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth; //<-- ignore this field for json serialization but not for deserialization
  Person({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}
```

When I use `JsonKey.ignore` the field is ignored for `toJson` and `fromJson`.

Is there a JsonKey Annotation for this case that I am missing?

Comment: I just found an open ticket for this issue https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/issues/569

Comment: It's been finally merged. Hoooray! Now there are `JsonKey.includeFromJson` and `JsonKey.includeToJson`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a workaround I've been using so I don't end up storing documentID's twice in my FB database while still having them available on the objects:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Exercise {
  const Exercise({
    @required this.documentID,
    // ...
  })  : assert(documentID != null);

  static toNull(_) => null; 
  @JsonKey(toJson: toNull, includeIfNull: false)
  final String documentID;

  //...

  factory Exercise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ExerciseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExerciseToJson(this);
}
```

where `toNull` is just

```dart
toNull(_) => null;
```

The toJson will null the value and then the includeIfNull won't serialize the value.

Comment: Let me know if this works with null safety. Answer is quite old and I haven't tested since

Comment: It works, make sure toNull is a static function and it is added at top level of class.

Comment: This is deprecated. @ABDO-AR has the right answer.

Answer (score 22):

With null safety it can be:

```
@JsonKey(ignore: true)
final String documentID;
```

Comment: This will actually throw an error when generating for a required field: `Cannot populate the required constructor argument: id. It is assigned to an ignored field.`
So, be careful with this suggestion.

Comment: This is deprecated, @ABDO-AR has the right answer

Answer (score 9):

As the latest version of the package it should be like that:

```
@JsonKey(includeFromJson: false, includeToJson: false)
final String documentID;
```